# Querying through "reportFilters" in reportMetadata with Analytics API

Tags: analytics

I am currently using the Analytics API to get report metadata. With the report ID, i can see a report, but I want to query through a particular report with a particular filter in reportFilters.

There is an example [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/sforce_analytics_rest_api_filter_reportdata.htm), but it doesn't provide what the REST url would look like to get that JSON response.

Is there a way to filter reports using the analytics API?

Answer (score 3):

It is the same url, but you have the filters in the request body
e.g.

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'/services/data/v29.0/analytics/reports/' + reportId,
    data: JSON.stringify({ reportMetadata: reportMetadata }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer {!$Api.Session_ID}');},
    success: function(response) {
        cb(response);
    }
});
```

The website you linked as an example of what reportMetadata looks like. Alternatively you can do a request to

```
'/services/data/v29.0/analytics/reports/' + reportId + '/describe'
```

and have a look at the reportMetadata there